Facebook privacy manifest update
Iam getting an error while integrating Facebook sdk.
ITMS-91061: Missing privacy manifest - Your app includes “Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit”, which includes FBSDKCoreKit, an SDK that was identified in the documentation as a privacy-impacting third-party SDK. Starting November 12, 2024, if a new app includes a privacy-impacting SDK, or an app update adds a new privacy-impacting SDK, the SDK must include a privacy manifest file. Please contact the provider of the SDK that includes this file to get an updated SDK version with a privacy manifest. For more details about this policy, including a list of SDKs that are required to include signatures and manifests, visit: https://developer.apple.com/support/third-party-SDK-requirements.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeDeviceInformation</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAnalytics</string>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAdvertising</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeProductInteraction</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAnalytics</string>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeProductPersonalization</string>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
            <string>CA92.1</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>NSPrivacyTracking</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyTrackingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPrivacyTrackingPurposes</key>
    <array>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAnalytics</string>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAdvertising</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSPrivacyTrackingDataTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeProductInteraction</string>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeDeviceInformation</string>
    </array>
</dict>

Please help to resolve this issue

To create a manifest

To add the privacy manifest to your app or third-party SDK in Xcode, follow these steps:
Choose File > New File.
Scroll down to the Resource section, and select App Privacy File type.
Click Next.
Check your app or third-party SDK’s target in the Targets list.
Click Create.
By default, the file is named PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy; this is the required file name for bundled privacy manifests.

Then in the Info.plist

At the top level of this property list file, add the following keys to the dictionary:


NSPrivacyTracking
A Boolean that indicates whether your app or third-party SDK uses data for tracking as defined under the App Tracking Transparency framework. For more information, see User Privacy and Data Use.


NSPrivacyTrackingDomains
An array of strings that lists the internet domains your app or third-party SDK connects to that engage in tracking. If the user has not granted tracking permission through the App Tracking Transparency framework, network requests to these domains fail and your app receives an error.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files#4284009
Facebook seems to have added the manifests with 17.0.0. So make sure you have the latest update.
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md
